# PEAR Crypt_Blowfish Error Encrypting MP3 File

Tags: php, performance, performance-testing

So, call me crazy (I know you will) but this is only for learning purposes. I'm doing some exploring with php and using PEAR Crypt_Blowfish on a line-by-line read of an mp3 file. It's very server intensive and I'm seeing strange output. I was wondering if anyone had insight as to why:

```
<?php
include_once '/home/.../php/Crypt/Blowfish.php';

$bf = new Crypt_Blowfish('super');

$handle = @fopen("Judith_full.mp3", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 1024)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
        echo '<br><br>ENCRYPTED: <br>';
        echo $bf->encrypt($buffer).'<br><br>';
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It's simply showing me the line, then the line encrypted... but part way through the page load I see text that is underlined:

```
....juMbLEDteXt_thenStartsUnderlinedJuMbLEDteXt_... // can not paste, cause it's encrypted garbage.
```

The page never full loads, just hangs. Also after the underlining it starts to ignore the `<br>`'s that are in there.

Thanks to anyone that takes the time.

Comment: The OP was in firefox testing. Chrome loads the page fully (way to go chrome!!) but has the same underlining... in fact, towards the bottom of the page it's underlined AND has a strikeout.